# Mongoid batch import fails, how to debug? MongoDB error log?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, debugging, mongoid

For reasons unknown, the following batch import is errenous:

```
Warehouse.collection.insert(chunk)
```

Where chunk is an array of hashes. I do this operation two times. One time with 1,000 warehouses and in the second iteration with 500 warehouses. Only the 1,000 warehouses get persisted in the database. I was able to validate this through `mongostat`, too.

What does work is basing the insert on Mongoid:

```
warehouses = warehouses.map { |attributes| Warehouse.new(attributes) }
warehouses.each { |warehouse| listing.warehouses << warehouse }
```

This is fine, but I would like to know what the problem with the batch import is.

How can I diagnose this problem? The `mongodb.log` only displays the open and closed disconnections. Is there something like an error log?

```
Warehouse.collection.insert(chunk, safe: true)
```

This didn't have me any information either.

Comment: Which version of Mongoid are you using, also which version of Moped or Mongo Ruby driver?

Comment: @GaryMurakami I am on Mongoid 3.1.5 and Moped 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

In the test below, please find examples that I hope will illuminate batch insertion in both Mongoid and Moped.
Test 1 shows how to successfully do batch insertion using Mongoid, and I recomment it instead of dropping down to Moped.
As you already know, the batch should be an array of hashes.
You can convert a Mongoid model to a hash by using #serializable_hash.

The Moped test show how to do batch insertion with Moped.
Included are tests for duplicate key insertion errors, both silent and with an exception raised.
I suspect that you did something similar to test #4 for this SO issue.

Hope that this helps.  Please let us know if you figure out your issue and can move ahead.

test/unit/warehouse_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'pp'

class WarehouseTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Warehouse.delete_all
    puts
  end
  def generate_warehouses(n = 1_000)
    n.times.collect { Warehouse.new.serializable_hash }
  end
  test "0. mongoid version" do
    puts "Mongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
  end
  test "1. mongoid batch insert" do
    Warehouse.create(generate_warehouses(1_000))
    Warehouse.create(generate_warehouses(500))
    assert_equal 1_500, Warehouse.count
  end
  test "2. mongoid batch re-insert" do
    warehouses = generate_warehouses(1_000)
    Warehouse.create(warehouses) # object ids will be generated at a lower level and not be added to warehouses
    Warehouse.create(warehouses) # no duplicate key errors here
    assert_equal 2_000, Warehouse.count
  end
  test "3. moped batch insert" do
    Warehouse.collection.insert(generate_warehouses(1_000))
    Warehouse.collection.insert(generate_warehouses(500))
    assert_equal 1_500, Warehouse.count
  end
  test "4. moped batch re-insert duplicate keys silent failure" do
    warehouses = generate_warehouses(1_000)
    Warehouse.collection.insert(warehouses) # object ids will be generated and added to warehouses as a side effect
    Warehouse.collection.insert(warehouses) # re-insertion of previous object ids will fail with duplicate key errors
    assert_equal 1_000, Warehouse.count
  end
  test "5. moped batch re-insert duplicate keys exception" do
    warehouses = generate_warehouses(1_000)
    Warehouse.mongo_session.with(safe: true) do |session|
      session.use(Warehouse.database_name)
      collection = session[:warehouses]
      collection.insert(warehouses) # object ids will be generated and added to warehouses as a side effect
      begin
        collection.insert(warehouses) # re-insertion of previous object ids will fail with duplicate key errors
      rescue => exception
        puts "exception.message: #{exception.message}"
      end
    end
    assert_equal 1_000, Warehouse.count
  end
end
```

rake test

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[1/6] WarehouseTest#test_0._mongoid_version
Mongoid::VERSION:3.1.5
Moped::VERSION:1.5.1
[2/6] WarehouseTest#test_1._mongoid_batch_insert            
[3/6] WarehouseTest#test_2._mongoid_batch_re-insert              
[4/6] WarehouseTest#test_3._moped_batch_insert                      
[5/6] WarehouseTest#test_4._moped_batch_re-insert_duplicate_keys_silent_failure
[6/6] WarehouseTest#test_5._moped_batch_re-insert_duplicate_keys_exception                      
exception.message: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=85
  @request_id=3525
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="sandbox_mongoid3_test.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:getlasterror=>1, :safe=>true}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 11000: "E11000 duplicate key error index: sandbox_mongoid3_test.warehouses.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('5283a3947f11ba868d001771') }"

See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md
for details about this error.
Finished tests in 3.069318s, 1.9548 tests/s, 1.6290 assertions/s.                          
6 tests, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```